# How to renew caption command to get bold title?

Tags: captions, bold

How to renew `\caption` command to make all title in bold?
I do this:

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,labelsep=space]{caption}
```

and I get

> **Figure 1** caption

I need

> **Figure 1 caption**

My try

```
\renewcommand{\caption}[1]{\caption{\textbf{#1}}}
```

doesn't work.

Comment: Add `font=bf` to the options. Or, better, change `labelfont` to `font`

Comment: BTW: The `caption` package does offer a documentation.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As **egreg** pointed out in his comment, since you are already loading the `caption` package, you don't need to redefine `\caption`; all you have to do is to use the option `font=bf` instead of just `labelfont=bf` (the latter affects the whole caption whilst the former only affects the caption label and separator); a little example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[font=bf,labelsep=space]{caption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for `\includegraphics`
\caption{A test figure}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another (but not so economic) option would have been to load `caption` on the following way

```
\usepackage[labelfont=bf,textfont=bf,labelsep=space]{caption}
```

Comment: How can I do in this similar thing using `subcaption` package?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps less flexible, you can modify `\@makecaption` to always print the caption in `\bfseries`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
% Taken from article.cls, although common to book.cls and report.cls
\long\def\@makecaption#1#2{%
  \vskip\abovecaptionskip
  \sbox\@tempboxa{\bfseries#1: #2}%
  \ifdim \wd\@tempboxa >\hsize
    \bfseries#1: #2\par
  \else
    \global \@minipagefalse
    \hb@xt@\hsize{\hfil\box\@tempboxa\hfil}%
  \fi
  \vskip\belowcaptionskip}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[ht]\caption{This is a figure caption}\end{figure}
\begin{table}[ht]\caption{This is a table caption}\end{table}
\end{document}
```